# How to assign primary key values into foreign keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I don't think that I could be specific in the title about my problem. Let me put it this way, getting away from talking about the project's content.

I have many of tables in my database, two of which are `Persons` and `Address`. In need of normalisation and setting many-to-many relations between these two entities, I don't keep any foreign keys in these tables referencing each other. For example, I don't store a foreign key to Address table, in Person table

Instead, my foreign keys are in a third table named `PersonAddress`. This table includes nothing but only two foreign keys referencing primary keys in their own tables (`Person`,`Address`)

In Microsoft SQL Server, we linked the table in question into the other two, making the attributes (`PersonId, AddressId`) of the table named `PersonAddress` **foreign keys** to the other two tables,  allowing delete and update cascading operation. (anyway)

At the first time, it seemed that it would work very well. However, once we kept inputting data into the database, it occurred that foreign key values remained unchanged in the third table, where we could see each primary key value in both tables Person and Address

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance for your prospective attempts, guys.

Comment: Have you added ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE while defining your foreign key?

Comment: Can you clarify on what statement you are executing, and what you think should be the effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did the right thing creating the intermediary table to create the many-to-many relationship and it appears to work as expected.

- SQL server will not automatically delete related items in the PersonAddress table, but will fail if you have not done so yourself
- I would put a primary key on that table across the two other ids - leaving them both as FKs too.

Please clarify the question if this does not answer it.

Comment: Make sure you look at DeepShikha's answer ... it appears you may be able to cascade updates and deletes.

Answer (score 1):

To reflect or cascade changes done in referenced columns in Parent table ( i.e., if you change values in primary key column of parent table), to be reflected in child tables as well( i.e., you want entires in child table foreign key column also to be updated with same values) you should add `Cascade` option while defining the foreign key.

as:

```
    create table PersonAddress 
   ( 
     PersonId int 
   , AddressId int
   ,CONSTRAINT FK_PersonId Foreign key (PersonId) 
    references Person(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
   ,CONSTRAINT FK_AddressId Foreign key (AddressId) 
    references Address(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
   );
```

As you already have table definition in place to modify a FOREIGN KEY constraint, we must first delete the existing FOREIGN KEY constraint and then re-create it with the new definition.
So, write as:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'FK_PersonId' AND [type] = 'F')
ALTER TABLE PersonAddress
DROP Constraint FK_PersonId

GO

ALTER TABLE PersonAddress
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PersonId]
FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) REFERENCES Person(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
GO
```

You can check a test run [here](http://rextester.com/WORKT3608)